# defaultvalue or a valid value that depends on the report parameter startdate forward dependencies are not valid

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am trying to develop a report the parameter has an issue, it gives me an error.

There are 2 parameters (the first is a *date range* like start and end date and the second is a *loan number*)

Whenever I select a date range the loan number parameter should go blank. If I input a loan number then date range should go blank.

What should I do?

> ERROR --report parameter startdate has a defaultvalue or a valid value
>   that depends on the report parameter startdate forward dependencies
>   are not valid

Comment: What you are describing is a circular relationship between parameters, which is not possible in SSRS, only backward dependencies can be created i.e. B -> A is ok but not A -> B

Answer (score 1):

I think the exact scenario you describe is not possible in SSRS.  The closest equivalent is to check the "Allow null value" setting for both Parameters.

Then (assuming you are deploying via Report Manager or SharePoint) the report user gets an extra checkbox they can use to determine which parameter they want to fill in. You cannot prevent them from specifying both parameters as null.  If that is an issue, you have to deal with that in your Dataset and/or Report Layout.